# why there is a definite article before "desired"

Tags: definite-article, determiners

I saw sentences like:

> In order to print part of a web page, I would select **the desired sections** and press command + p.
>
> To register your courses, select **the desired sections** in the Find column and click Submit.

Why there is "the" before the phrase? It is not specific what are the desired sections of the user. could it be just "desired sections" or "your desired sections"?

Comment: See: determiner

Answer (score 3):

The meaning is:

> To register your courses, select the sections **that you desire to choose at that particular moment** in the Find column and click Submit.

The noun **sections** is "*modified*" by **desired**, and this modification makes the noun definite in this particular context.

You can say "your desired sections":

> To register your courses, select **your desired sections** in the Find column and click Submit.

The word **your** will occupy the slot that **the** occupied. Both **your** and **the** serve as "determiners" to the noun "sections". The word **your** will basically mean the same as **the** in this particular context. Since we cannot combine two "main determiners" like **the** and **your** (we can't say "**the your** desired sections"), we only use either **the** or **your**.

Compare with a sentence I've composed:

> To make a flower bouquet for my girl, I pick **red flowers** in the field.

By not using any determiner before "red flowers", I signal to the reader that I pick *any* red flowers I might find attractive enough, not some red flowers I selected beforehand.

---

P.S.

In on-screen messages, articles may be omitted in order to economize screen space:

> To register your courses, select desired sections in the Find column and click Submit.

---

References:

- [Possessive determiners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possessive_determiner#Possessive_determiners_in_English) - Wikipedia (**your** is a possessive determiner)

Comment: Thank you, however meanwhile I replaced it with another example, but when I saw your answer I  left two examples.

Comment: @Ahmad - fine, I reworked my answer.

Comment: What if one use just "select desired sections", what could it mean? aren't adjectives the modifier of nouns?

Comment: @Ahmad - adjectives are modifiers, but they are not determiners. The presence of the absence of this or that determiner (or all determiners) shows the "definiteness" and "belonging" of the noun to the reader (roughly speaking)